# String expansion for conditional inverse text normalization in text2num processing

Tags: python

```
def string_expansion(sent):
    list_str = sent.split(" ")
    new_list = []
    for index,char in enumerate(list_str):
        if char == "double":
            index +=1
            new_chars = (' '.join([list_str[index][:]] * 1))
            new_list = [x.replace(char , new_chars).replace(char , new_chars) for x in list_str]

        elif char == "triple":
            index +=1
            new_chars = (' '.join([list_str[index][:]] * 2))
            new_list = [x.replace(char , new_chars).replace(char , new_chars) for x in list_str]
        else:
            new_list
        
    return (" ".join(new_list))

    sentence = "my phone number is nine double eight five eight two eight triple seven"
    result = string_expansion(sentence)
    print(result)
```

**Actual output:** my phone number is nine double eight five eight two eight seven seven seven

**Expected output:** my phone number is nine eight eight five eight two eight seven seven seven

I am working on the inverse text normalization problem. In this process, I need to expand strings based on the condition (double or triple) so that numerical words will pass to the text2num function and produce results.

Comment: Changing the index variable in a `for` loop in Python does nothing. If you need to do non-standard things to the index variable, you need to use a `while` loop.

Comment: You completely replace the contents of `new_list` in the first two clauses of your `if`, and just have the non-operation `new_list` sitting in the third - the reason you're seeing the result you're seeing is because it just so happens that the replacement of the 'third' sets it to that specific result.

Comment: Also, please, fix the indentation of your snippet. And don't use `string` as name, it's a module from the Standard Library

Answer (score 1):

double means that the next item needs to be repeated twice, so replace the word double with one "next item" and trible with two "next items"

```
def string_expansion(string):
    list_str = string.split(" ")
    new_list = []
    for index, char in enumerate(list_str):
        if char == "double":
            new_list.append(list_str[index+1])

        elif char == "triple":
            new_list.extend([list_str[index+1]] * 2)
        else:
            new_list.append(list_str[index])

    return " ".join(new_list)


string = "my phone number is nine double eight five eight two eight triple seven"
result = string_expansion(string)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
my phone number is nine eight eight five eight two eight seven seven seven
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but regex can get you there a bit more quickly.

```
import re

text = "nine double eight five eight two eight triple seven"

def string_expansion(st):
    expand_doubles = re.sub(r'double (\w+)', r'\1 \1', st)
    expand_triples = re.sub(r'triple (\w+)', r'\1 \1 \1', expand_doubles)
    
    return expand_triples
    
expanded = string_expansion(text)
print(expanded)
```

> nine eight eight five eight two eight seven seven seven

You could easily create the replacement expressions for 'quadruple' and 'quintuple' if that became necessary.